# Getting setState is not defined no-undef error using React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am just getting started with React. So I generated a new React app with `npx create-react-app .` and it generated me a what I think is functional React hooks components. I guess this is the 2020 version.

But I ran into a problem when I tried to update my state. I basically wanted to toggle the `completed` property of the selected todo item. But when I called the `setTodos` method it gave me this error:

> index.js:1 ./src/App.js
>   Line 27:5:  'setTodos' is not defined  no-undef

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Todos from './components/Todos.js'

function App()
{
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
      { id: 1, title: 'First todo item', completed: false },
      { id: 2, title: 'Second todo item', completed: true },
      { id: 3, title: 'Third todo item', completed: false },
  ])

  return (
      <div>
        <Todos
            todos={todos}
            markComplete={ (event, todo) => markComplete(event, todo) }
        />
      </div>
  )
}

function markComplete(event, todo)
{
    // this works
    console.log('You clicked todo with id: ' + todo.id + ' and title: ' + todo.title)

    // setTodos is not defined...?
    setTodos({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Test',
      completed: true,
    })
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTodos` is only in scope within the function it is defined in, in this case the `App` component. Move `markComplete` into your component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Todos from './components/Todos.js'

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
      { id: 1, title: 'First todo item', completed: false },
      { id: 2, title: 'Second todo item', completed: true },
      { id: 3, title: 'Third todo item', completed: false },
  ]);

  function markComplete(event, todo) {
    console.log('You clicked todo with id: ' + todo.id + ' and title: ' + todo.title)

    setTodos({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Test',
      completed: true,
    })
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <Todos
            todos={todos}
            markComplete={ (event, todo) => markComplete(event, todo) }
        />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `markComplete` in the same function scope as `setTodos`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Todos from './components/Todos.js'

function App()
{
  function markComplete(event, todo)
  {
      setTodos({
          id: 1,
          title: 'Test',
          completed: true,
      })
  }

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
      { id: 1, title: 'First todo item', completed: false },
      { id: 2, title: 'Second todo item', completed: true },
      { id: 3, title: 'Third todo item', completed: false },
  ])

  return (
      <div>
        <Todos
            todos={todos}
            markComplete={ (event, todo) => markComplete(event, todo) }
        />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

**State**

- state use only inside a component.
- state change a value inside a component.

So you must put the function **markComplete** inside your component **App**.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Todos from './components/Todos.js'

function App()
{
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
      { id: 1, title: 'First todo item', completed: false },
      { id: 2, title: 'Second todo item', completed: true },
      { id: 3, title: 'Third todo item', completed: false },
  ])
const markComplete = (event, todo) =>
    {
        setTodos({
            id: 1,
          title: 'Test',
          completed: true,
      })
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <Todos
            todos={todos}
            markComplete={ (event, todo) => markComplete(event, todo) }
        />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Bru, I noticed you changed the markComplete function to an arrow function, is there any particular reason for this change? Is this better?

Comment: @Liga, for react hooks there is no difference, The arrow function would automatically bind (lexical this) to the instance of your class component and you don't have to bind it in the constructor. In your case you use Hooks so there is no difference but i'am usually use arrow function.